# Doesn't print what expected, Error in function Travasa?

Tags: c++, templates, stack, queue

I have to implement 2 template class: Queue and Stack
And in stack class I have to implement the function Travasa() that should take the element from the current stack and Enqueue them into the Queue;
I have to read a series of operation from the input file and get an output file

**input from file is:**

bool 10 e:0 p:0 p:1 travasa p:1 e:1 pop e:1 dequeue e:0

char 10 e:g p:k e:j e:h travasa p:f p:o e:n pop p:e

char 10 p:c travasa p:n dequeue travasa p:p e:o dequeue e:p travasa

int 10 e:7 p:88 p:42 pop pop e:82 e:12 p:54 e:49 travasa

**output should be:**

1 0 1 1 0

g j h k n

o p p

7 82 12 49 54

**but my output is:**

0 1 0

g j h n

p

7 82 12 49

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream infile("input.txt");
ofstream outfile("output.txt");

template<typename T> class Queue
{
private:
    T * values;
    int dim;
    int Top;
public:
    Queue(int L):dim(L){
        values=new T[L];
        dim=L;
        Top=-1;
    };

    ~Queue(){
        delete values;
    }

    void Enqueue(T value);
    void Dequeue();
    void Print();
};
template <typename T> void Queue<T>:: Enqueue(T value){
    if(Top<dim){
    Top++;
    values[Top]=value;
    }
    else cerr<< "Queue is Full!"<< endl;
}


template <typename T> void Queue<T>:: Dequeue(){
    if(Top>=0)
    Top--;
    else cerr<< "Queue already empty"<< endl;
}

template <typename T> void Queue<T>:: Print(){
    for(int i=0; i<=Top; i++) outfile<< values[i]<< " ";
}

template <typename T> class Stack
{
private:
    T * values;
    int dim;
    int top;
public:
    Stack(int L): dim(L){
        values=new T [L];
        top=L;
    } ;
    ~Stack(){
        delete values;
    };


    void Push(T value);
    void Pop();
    void Print();
    void Travasa(Queue <T> A);
};

template <typename T> void Stack<T>:: Push(T value){
    top--;
    if(top>=0)
    values[top]=value;
    else cerr<< "Stack is Full!"<< endl;
}

template <typename T> void Stack<T>:: Pop(){
    if(top<dim)
    top++;
    else cerr<< "Stack is already empty"<< endl;
}

template <typename T> void Stack<T>:: Print(){
    for(int i=top; i<dim; i++) outfile<< values[i]<< " ";
}

template <typename T> void Stack<T>::Travasa(Queue <T> A){
   for(int i=top; i<dim; i++) {
       A.Enqueue(values[i]);
       Pop();
    }

}


int main(){

    int c=0, N;
    string tipo,operazione;

    for(c=0; c<4; c++){
        cout<<"prova"<< endl;
        infile>>tipo>> N;
        if(tipo=="int"){
            Queue<int> A(N);
            Stack<int> B(N);
            for(int j=0; j<N;j++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione== "travasa")
                B.Travasa(A);
                else if(operazione=="pop")
                B.Pop();
                else if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.Dequeue();
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="e:")
                {
                    int elemento=stoi(operazione.substr(2));
                    A.Enqueue(elemento);    
                }
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="p:")
                {
                    int elemento=stoi(operazione.substr(2));
                    B.Push(elemento);
                }

            }
            A.Print();
            //A.~Queue();
            //B.~Stack();
            outfile<< endl;
        }
        if(tipo=="double"){
            Queue<double> A(N);
            Stack<double> B(N);
            for(int j=0; j<N;j++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione== "travasa")
                B.Travasa(A);
                else if(operazione=="pop")
                B.Pop();
                else if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.Dequeue();
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="e:")
                {
                    double elemento=stod(operazione.substr(2));
                    A.Enqueue(elemento);    
                }
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="p:")
                {
                    double elemento=stod(operazione.substr(2));
                    B.Push(elemento);
                }

            }
            A.Print();
            A.~Queue();
            B.~Stack();            
            outfile<< endl;        
        }
        if(tipo=="bool"){
            Queue<int> A(N);
            Stack<int> B(N);
            for(int j=0; j<N;j++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione== "travasa")
                B.Travasa(A);
                else if(operazione=="pop")
                B.Pop();
                else if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.Dequeue();
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="e:")
                {
                    bool elemento=stoi(operazione.substr(2));

                    A.Enqueue(elemento);    
                }
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="p:")
                {
                    bool elemento=stoi(operazione.substr(2));
                    B.Push(elemento);
                }

            }
            A.Print();
            A.~Queue();
            B.~Stack();            
            outfile<< endl;    
        }
        if(tipo=="char"){
            Queue<char> A(N);
            Stack<char> B(N);
            for(int j=0; j<N;j++){
                infile>> operazione;
                if(operazione== "travasa")
                B.Travasa(A);
                else if(operazione=="pop")
                B.Pop();
                else if(operazione=="dequeue")
                A.Dequeue();
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="e:")
                {
                    string elemento=operazione.substr(2);
                    A.Enqueue(elemento[0]);    
                }
                else if(operazione.substr(0,2)=="p:")
                {
                    string elemento=operazione.substr(2);
                    B.Push(elemento[0]);
                }

            }
            A.Print();
            A.~Queue();
            B.~Stack();
            outfile<< endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You need to read up on [rule-of-three/five/zero concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). There are at least four places in this code where your completely non-rule-of-three compliant template class Queue undergoes copy-construction and/or copy-assignment. With compiler-default copy-ctor and copy-assignment, you're making shallow copies of the internals of Queue, and creating scenarios where multiple objects "own" the same internal dynamic array. So what happens when one of those objects destroys it's array? What does the *other* object now point to... Hmm.

Comment: Mmh I'm reading, but I'm not understanding so well... I'm a newbie... Could you explain to me how it works easily, please?

Comment: That's what the link is for. Further, the manual firing of destructors is nonsense. The only time that is ever required is in a coding condition involving a pattern called *placement-new*, and you're definitely not utilizing that pattern.

Comment: Simply put you need to implement copy constructors and assignment operators for your classes and you need to remove the explicit calls to destructors from your code.

Comment: Or, you need to realize that your classes shouldn't allow copying, and the main place where it happens is an argument passed by value that should be passed by reference. Disabling copying of `Queue` and `Stack` instances will provide insight as to where those mistakes are happening, because the code will no longer compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be.. involved. There are a plethora of things wrong in your existing code. Breaking the code down into smaller, more manageable parts, makes it easier to discover what those problems are.

---

**Broken Dequeue**

This is one of the more subtle problems. Your operations for Dequeue are simply wrong. Your queue is based on a sequence that is initially empty and whose "Top" always refers to the "back" of the queue (where items go in). As you add items, t `Top` is increased and the new item is stored at `values[Top]`.

But you don't stick with that design during *dequeue* operations. Remember, a queue is a FIFO (first in first out). That means the items at the beginning of `values` are the ones that need to be removed. With your current design (a noncircular queue), that means some shifting "down" of elements is required, but you do no such thing. rather, you're Dequeue looks like this:

```
template <typename T> void Queue<T>:: Dequeue(){
    if(Top>=0)
       Top--;
    else cerr<< "Queue already empty"<< endl;
}
```

That's wrong. This is treating your queue like a *stack*. It should look like this:

```
template <typename T> void Queue<T>:: Dequeue(){
{
    if (Top >= 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<Top; ++i)
            values[i] = values[i+1];
        --Top;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr<< "Queue already empty"<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

**Broken Rule Of Three/Five/Zero Compliance**

Whether you realize it or not, your classes, specifically `Queue<T>`, are undergoing undesired copying. They're not prepared for it. This:

```
template <typename T> void Stack<T>::Travasa(Queue <T> A){
   for(int i=top; i<dim; i++) {
       A.Enqueue(values[i]);
       Pop();
    }
}
```

Look at the `A` argument. It's by value.  That means two things.

- `A` is a default-copy of the caller's argument.
- Because of incorrect rule-of-three/five/zero compliance, now both objects (`A` here and the caller side variable) have dynamic pointers that point to the *same* data. When one of them is free'd the other is left with a dangling pointer and a further dereference leads to *undefined behavior*.

To accommodate the specific problem. `Travesa` should take `A` by reference. It is clearly modifying it. Later. We can shore up the two class templates `Queue` and `Stack` to make sure they no longer allow this kind of mistake.

First the member function:

```
template <typename T> void Stack<T>::Travasa(Queue <T>& A)
{
    for(int i=top; i<dim; i++)
        A.Enqueue(values[i]);
    top = dim;
}
```

Optionally make sure this doesn't happen again by making those two classes non-copyable. It's pretty simple. First create a simple base class `NonCopyable` :

```
class NonCopyable
{
protected:
    NonCopyable() {}

private:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator =(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

Now, just inherit your two class templates from that. For example, this is what it looks like for `Queue`:

```
template<typename T>
class Queue : public NonCopyable
{
    // ... implementation
}
```

Now any place you attempt to make value copies of `Queue` instantiations your compiler will complain and you'll see right where the problem is.

---

**Divide And Conquer**

You have a LOT of dense code in your `main()` attempting to do many things. But what if you didn't need it? What if you handled each operation line as it's own entity in its own function. For example, suppose you had a `process_int` line to handle the integer transformations of a command line sequence. It could look something like this:

```
void process_int(int N, std::istream& inp, std::ostream& outp)
{
    Queue<int> A(N);
    Stack<int> B(N);
    std::string op;

    while (N-- && inp >> op)
    {
        if(op == "travasa")
            B.Travasa(A);

        else if(op=="pop")
            B.Pop();

        else if(op=="dequeue")
            A.Dequeue();

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="e:")
        {
            int elemento=stoi(op.substr(2));
            A.Enqueue(elemento);
        }

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="p:")
        {
            B.Push(std::stoi(op.substr(2)));
        }
    }
    outp << A << '\n';
}
```

The only thing in this code that isn't compliant with your implementation is the final output, which uses an operator overload (I'll get to that in a minute). But hopefully you can see how much cleaner this is. It's obvious exactly what is happening. From this, another version, this time for `char`

```
void process_char(int N, std::istream& inp, std::ostream& outp)
{
    Queue<char> A(N);
    Stack<char> B(N);
    std::string op;

    while (N-- && inp >> op)
    {
        if(op== "travasa")
            B.Travasa(A);

        else if(op=="pop")
            B.Pop();

        else if(op=="dequeue")
            A.Dequeue();

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="e:")
            A.Enqueue(op[2]);

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="p:")
            B.Push(op[2]);
    }

    outp << A << '\n';
}
```

Again, see how much easier it is to understand what is going on.

---

**Putting It All Together**

The final version of all of this appears below. Among the many changes:

- Fixed Dequeue operation
- Added non-copyable base class to prevent accidental copies
- Added per-line processing
- Added print-on-stream support, and `operator <<` overloads.
- Modularized the handling of each type of command line being processed.
- Moved the files to `main` where they belong

The result looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class NonCopyable
{
protected:
    NonCopyable() {}

private:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator =(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};


template<typename T>
class Queue : public NonCopyable
{
private:
    T * values;
    int dim;
    int Top;
public:
    Queue(int L)
        : values(new T[L])
        , dim(L)
        , Top(-1)
    {
    };

    virtual ~Queue()
    {
        delete [] values;
    }

    void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        if(Top<dim){
            Top++;
            values[Top]=value;
        }
        else std::cerr<< "Queue is Full!"<< std::endl;
    }

    void Dequeue()
    {
        if (Top >= 0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<Top; ++i)
                values[i] = values[i+1];
            --Top;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr<< "Queue already empty"<< std::endl;
        }
    }

    void Print(std::ostream& outp) const
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=Top; i++)
            outp << values[i] << ' ';
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Queue<T> const& q)
    {
        q.Print(os);
        return os;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Stack : public NonCopyable
{
private:
    T * values;
    int dim;
    int top;
public:
    Stack(int L)
        : values( new T[L]() )
        , dim( L )
        , top( L )
    {
    }

    virtual ~Stack()
    {
        delete [] values;
    }

    void Push(T value)
    {
        if (top > 0)
        {
            values[--top]=value;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Stack is Full!"<< std::endl;
        }
    }

    void Pop()
    {
        if (top < dim)
            ++top;
        else
            std::cerr<< "Stack is already empty"<< std::endl;
    }

    // queues all the items on the stack. resets the stack
    void Travasa(Queue <T>& A)
    {
        for(int i=top; i<dim; i++)
            A.Enqueue(values[i]);
        top = dim;
    }

    void Print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        for (int i=top; i<dim; ++i)
            os << values[i] << ' ';
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Stack<T> const& st)
    {
        st.Print(os);
        return os;
    }
};


// int commands
void process_int(int N, std::istream& inp, std::ostream& outp)
{
    Queue<int> A(N);
    Stack<int> B(N);
    std::string op;

    while (N-- && inp >> op)
    {
        if(op == "travasa")
            B.Travasa(A);

        else if(op=="pop")
            B.Pop();

        else if(op=="dequeue")
            A.Dequeue();

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="e:")
        {
            int elemento=stoi(op.substr(2));
            A.Enqueue(elemento);
        }

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="p:")
        {
            B.Push(std::stoi(op.substr(2)));
        }
    }
    outp << A << '\n';
}

// char sequence
void process_char(int N, std::istream& inp, std::ostream& outp)
{
    Queue<char> A(N);
    Stack<char> B(N);
    std::string op;

    while (N-- && inp >> op)
    {
        if(op== "travasa")
            B.Travasa(A);

        else if(op=="pop")
            B.Pop();

        else if(op=="dequeue")
            A.Dequeue();

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="e:")
            A.Enqueue(op[2]);

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="p:")
            B.Push(op[2]);
    }

    outp << A << '\n';
}

// double sequence
void process_double(int N, std::istream& inp, std::ostream& outp)
{
    Queue<double> A(N);
    Stack<double> B(N);
    std::string op;

    while (N-- && inp >> op)
    {
        if(op== "travasa")
            B.Travasa(A);

        else if(op=="pop")
            B.Pop();

        else if(op=="dequeue")
            A.Dequeue();

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="e:")
            A.Enqueue(std::stod(op.substr(2)));

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="p:")
            B.Push(stod(op.substr(2)));
    }

    outp << A << '\n';
}

// bool sequence
void process_bool(int N, std::istream& inp, std::ostream& outp)
{
    Queue<int> A(N);
    Stack<int> B(N);
    std::string op;

    while (N-- && inp >> op)
    {
        if(op == "travasa")
            B.Travasa(A);

        else if(op == "pop")
            B.Pop();

        else if(op == "dequeue")
            A.Dequeue();

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="e:")
            A.Enqueue(std::stoi(op.substr(2)));

        else if(op.substr(0,2)=="p:")
            B.Push(std::stoi(op.substr(2)));
    }

    outp << A << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    std::ofstream outfile("output.txt");

    // per line processing
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string type;
        int n;
        if (iss >> type >> n && n > 0)
        {
            if (type == "int")
                process_int(n, iss, outfile);

            else if (type == "char")
                process_char(n, iss, outfile);

            else if (type == "double")
                process_double(n, iss, outfile);

            else if (type == "bool")
                process_bool(n, iss, outfile);
        }
    }
}
```

**Input File**

```
bool 10 e:0 p:0 p:1 travasa p:1 e:1 pop e:1 dequeue e:0
char 10 e:g p:k e:j e:h travasa p:f p:o e:n pop p:e
char 10 p:c travasa p:n dequeue travasa p:p e:o dequeue e:p travasa
int 10 e:7 p:88 p:42 pop pop e:82 e:12 p:54 e:49 travasa
```

**Output File**

```
1 0 1 1 0
g j h k n
o p p
7 82 12 49 54
```